# Display my work laptop on gaming desktop

Tags: windows, thinkpad, displayport, usb-c

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this..

Anyhow, I as many others are currently working from home. My job issued me a standard ThinkPad laptop that I have hooked up to my monitors. The issue is that I want to be able to easily switch over to my gaming PC, as of now I have to go behind and switch DisplayPort cables..

So my question is, can I somehow connect my ThinkPad laptop to my gaming computer and have it as a window on my gaming pc?
I am looking for something like TeamViewer but with little latency.

Comment: What Windows flavor is installed on your work laptop (Home, Pro, Enterprise, ..)?

Comment: I got a dual monitor KVM for more or less the same circumstances.  Its not perfect, but does let me comply with company policies.

Comment: I am with @FrankThomas , I think a KVM is probably your best bet.  Depending on your companies policies.. I myself would *live* on my gaming PC and RDC into my work desktop and skip the KVM altogether since lag won't be an issue if you aren't gaming.

Comment: @Robert We are using Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2.

Comment: I will do some research into KVM, do you mind elaborating a litte bit more about KVM. I know that its a form of vm on linux, does that mean I need to change my main OS to Linux? @FrankThomas

Comment: In Windows 10 Enterprise the RDP server is available if you have the permissions to activate and use it. Using that you could remote login to Windows and see and control everything via a Network connection.

Comment: KVM literally stands for Keyboard, Video, (and) Mouse. its like an A|B switch you can use to connect two computers to the same keyboard/monitor/mouse, and switch between them by pressing a button on the KVM, or using a key command that usually starts with hitting Scroll Lock twice. Be sure to get one that supports both the kinds of video output/input plugs you have (so HDMI end to end or DisplayPort end to end). if you do need adapters because you have HDMI Monitors but DP ports,  make sure you get active adapters. a kvm, is a hardware device and is generally os agnostic. not linux KVM.

Comment: @Robert There is already to much remote desktop use for my taste, I fear that it will start lagging. I will look into it though, thanks!